# How to Use UiApplication.activate() in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I want to use the `UiApplication.activate()` method in BlackBerry.  In Android, we use the `onResume()` method; so how do we use the `UiApplication.activate()` method in BlackBerry?

There is not that much info available.

Comment: There is generally no need to use any method similar to `onResume()` in blackberry. You can do whatever you do in android in `onResume()` in the Screen constructor itself. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: is it possible to use onResume() method in blackberry

Comment: You did not answer why you want to use it? There is no onResume() method in BlackBerry although there are others which can be used depending on your needs.

Comment: i want to make change in my UI after clicking on button i want to remove slider field after clicking on button and vise versa

Comment: You can simply pass a variable that references the sliderfield and its manager to the button's `FieldChangeListener`. Using that you can add / remove / modify the field. Please note that unlike android, the screens are not serialized so you can work with the field object like you would do in ordinary java.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to answer this question because of the comment below Peter's answer.  [Activity#onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) in Android is not normally used simply *"to refresh ... UI data on the spot after making changes"*.

### Android

`onResume()` is called by the Android OS when a user comes (back) to an `Activity`; this usually happens after leaving it ... either because another Activity was displayed in front of it, or because the user left your application and came back to it (going home and back, to the phone and back, etc.)

[image]

### BlackBerry

In BlackBerry, `Application#activate()` is called when the user returns to your **app**.  This callback happens at the **app** level.  An app in Android is made of many Activies (normally).  `onResume()` gets called separately for each Activity in your app, as the user returns to *that individual Activity*.

Although not identical, a similar construct in BlackBerry is the `Screen` class.  One app may have many Screens, as Android apps have many Activities.  So, if you're looking for the most similar thing to `onResume()`, I would try, [as Peter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724111/119114):

- [Screen#onExposed()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onExposed())
- [Screen#onUiEngineAttached(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onUiEngineAttached(boolean))

To get closest to `onResume()`, you probably need both of those methods, because `Screen#onExposed()` does not get called the **first** time your `Screen` is shown (while `Activity#onResume()` does).  You would override these methods in your own classes that extend `Screen` (or `MainScreen`, etc.)

If your problem is just determining when to refresh your UI, you'll need to explain more about what kind of UI objects (Fields) you're using, and **when** you get new data to display.

### Update:

Here is some sample code for how you might build your main `Screen` class, to try to mimic Android's `onResume()` callback:

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
   public MyScreen() {        
      setTitle("MyTitle");
   }

   protected void onExposed() {
      super.onExposed();
      onResume();
   }

   protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
      super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
      if (attached) {
         onResume();
      }
   }

   private void onResume() {
      // TODO: put your Android-like processing here
      System.out.println("onResume()");
   }
}
```

Comment: any idea how i used above methods?

Comment: You would create a class that is a subclass of (`extends`) the `Screen` class, or maybe `MainScreen`.  In your class, you would then override both the `onExposed()` and `onUiEngineAttached(boolean)` methods.  The processing you would do in Android during `onResume()` would be put into `onExposed()` and `onUiEngineAttached()`.  `onUiEngineAttached()` will be called both when "creating", and "destroying", in Android terminology.  So, you need to check that the Boolean parameter is equal to true.  Is that enough to get you going?  If not, let me know, and I can put some more code into my answer.

Comment: no its not working it is get activate  on launch screen  its not getting functional whenever i returned from the slider menu

Comment: It's working, but you didn't pose your question clearly.  My answer is basically responding to the question *"how do you imitate Android's onResume() in BlackBerry?"*.  You also have made comments about wanting to update your fields when the user clicks a button or moves a slider. But, that is **not** what you would use `onResume()` for in Android.  You really should post the **code** you're using for the button and slider, and more clearly state (*in the question*) what you're trying to do.  Please post a **new** question for this, otherwise, you make the two existing answers useless. Thanks.

Comment: http://paste2.org/hDLYHsfF see the code i used its not working and remember my button is not the on the mainscreen it is on my slider menu screen

Comment: r u available on stack overflow chat room? if possible we can discuss there i am also not able to explain properly here

Comment: sorry, I'm not available for chat. I can look at your new question in a couple hours, though.  thanks for posting a new question.

Comment: that is not related to this question  its new one please come on stack overflow if possible to you

Comment: can i contact u on u r mail id? please its very urgent

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing really to know about activate().  If you look at the documentation

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html

it says:
"The system invokes this method when it brings this application to the foreground."

So if your application has been pushed to the background (for example, by a phone call), and then the user clicks on your icon to look at your application again, then activate() will be called.  By contrast, deactivate() will be called when the system pushes your application to the background (for example, when a phone call is received).

Note that activate() is also called when the application is first started.

The question really is what do you do in onResume() that you need to replicate in the BlackBerry code.  If you can tell us this, we might be able to suggest what is the best way to achieve the result you want.

**Update**

Given that you appear to be using onResume() to update a Ui, there is unfortunately, no one simple way of doing this for the entire application.  The method you would use actually depends on what is being updated.

But be aware that most Fields are updated automatically when you change their contents. To give a simple example, if you have an EditField that contains data, and you use the 
.setText("new data");
method, this will automatically repaint that Field on the screen for you.

I expect that you have a screen that you have populated from the database or data source, and in activate() you want to refresh this data.  So you will have to go through each of the screen's Fields and use the associated set... method to update the contents.

This is slightly problematic, because activate is called for the Application, not the screen, and you might have multiple screens on the stack, and you really need to update all of them  There are various methods available to do this, involving say, your screens registering themselves to be updated, or your activate() method searching the display stack for the screens there.

But possibly a simple approach is to use each screen's 'onExposed()' method to automatically update the contents.  This method is called anytime the screen is hidden and then shown, which is exactly what would happen after the application has been foregrounded.  It also happens when the screen is hidden by another screen being pushed on top of it, or even a user pressing the menu key.  So perhaps, if the update is time consuming (for example requires a database lookup), you might want not want to update every time onExposed() is invoked, but instead try to restrict the update frequency.

This 'onExposed()' approach does not get out of the requirement to update the contents of each Field separately, but it might make it easier to implement.

**Further update**

Note Nate's answer, Nate has experience of both Android and BB, so can better relate to your problem.

But if you know that the screen has been updated, so you have just processed a network request that relates t that screens content, then you should go through each of the Field individually, "set"ting the updated value at that time, don't worry about using onExposed().  One design approach that accommodates this is to separate the screen construction from the screen population, so you can call the 'population' from multiple places (note that you do need to be on the Event Thread when you update the Fields).

But in this circumstance, you might find it easier and faster to create a new Screen and push that and pop the old screen (which has the old values).

Comment: I want to refresh my UI data on the spot after making changes,for that we use onResume() method in android like that what we use in blackberry?